# OverlapAreaAll doesn`t detect collider unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

The situation is this: there is a method that moves all the boxes in the level to the starting position.

```
private void OnPlayerinteract(Transform player)
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position) < TriggerDiastance)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
        {
            boxes[i].position = puzzleData.GetBoxPosIndex(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < levers.Length; i++)
        {
            levers[i].SwitchLaver(puzzleData.GetLeverStateIndex(i));
        }
    }
    RestartPuzzle?.Invoke();
}
```

The RestartPuzzle event calls a method on the pressure plates to check to see if they have the boxes they just moved. Here's the method:

```
private void CheckColliders()
{
    Collider2D[] collider2Ds = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(
        new Vector2((transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        new Vector2((transform.position.x + transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y + transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)));
    Debug.DrawLine(
        new Vector2((transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        new Vector2((transform.position.x + transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y + transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        Color.blue,
        100f);
    foreach (var item in collider2Ds)
    {
        if (item.GetComponent<Presser>())
        {
            Debug.Log(item.name);
            signalState = SignalState.On;
            foreach (Interactable i in Interactables)
            {
                i.OnTriggerDone();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The CheckColliders method only finds the pressure plate collider, even though the box is inside the area. The collider is found only when the method is executed twice(when I press the button twice).
Any ideas how to fix this problem?

I tried
making colliders smaller and larger
using OverlapBox instead of OverlapAreaAll
checking the collider twice in a row.

Update: if i check collider after 0.05 sec delay all works perfectly, but how can i do it without delay? I think this must not be a problem but why unity cant find collider if its relocation was done before check?

Comment: how/who/what calls the first set of code and the same again for the second.. there is no link here between the two no indication to show order of running or anything please read [mcve]